# Android: RadioGroup OnCheckedChangeListener in the first view add with for loop doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I added views to the Activity with for loop and each view has a radioGroup with different listener, dealing with index of for loop. However, I got some problems while testing my app.

1. OnCheckedChangeListener operates well in other views except the first add view. 
   I confirmed that listener is attatched to the radioGroup of the first view with Log. However, clearCheck() other views' radioGroups does not work.
2. I have to click twice radioGroups of the second or higher index views to activate them. 
    
   How can I solve this problem? 
   Below is my code.

### JAVA

```
for (int i=players.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    final View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.board, null);
    if (i == 0)
        RadioGroup radioA = mView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    else if (i == 1)
        RadioGroup radioB = mView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    else if (i == 2)
        RadioGroup radioC = mView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    // RadioGroup onCheckChangeListeners
    aListener = (group, checkedId) -> {
        index2 = 0;
        radioClicked(checkedId);

        if (radioB != null) {
            radioB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            radioB.clearCheck();
            radioB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(bListener);
        }
        if (radioC != null) {
            radioC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            radioC.clearCheck();
            radioC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cListener);
        }
    };
    bListener = (group, checkedId) -> {
        index2 = 1;
        radioClicked(checkedId);

        radioA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        radioA.clearCheck();
        radioA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(aListener);
        if (radioC != null) {
            radioC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            radioC.clearCheck();
            radioC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cListener);
        }
    };
    cListener = (group, checkedId) -> {
    index2 = 2;
    radioClicked(checkedId);

    radioA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    radioA.clearCheck();
    radioA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(aListener);
    radioB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    radioB.clearCheck();
    radioB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(bListener);
    };  

    try {
        radioA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(aListener);
    } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
    }
    try {
        radioB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(bListener);
    } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
    }
    try {
        radioC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(bListener);
    } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
    }

    ActivityView.addView(mView);
}
```

Comment: Why  radioA,B,C have the same R.id.radioGroup? Could add your xml code about RadioGroup.

Comment: @Anna because I add view sharing same layout with for loop. It is just a normal radio group